# Magnitude of sum of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Say I have

> $|\overrightarrow x + \overrightarrow y|$, where $\overrightarrow x,\overrightarrow y $ are vectors

I get that,

$$|\overrightarrow x + \overrightarrow y| = (\overrightarrow x+\overrightarrow y)\cdot (\overrightarrow x + \overrightarrow y)$$

Can I claim

$(\overrightarrow x + \overrightarrow y) \cdot (\overrightarrow x +\overrightarrow y) = \overrightarrow x\cdot \overrightarrow x + 2 (\overrightarrow x \cdot \overrightarrow y) + \overrightarrow y \cdot \overrightarrow y$? If so, how?

Comment: Yes due to distributivity of dot product.

Comment: Is it square in first line i.e. $$|\overrightarrow x + \overrightarrow y|^2 = (\overrightarrow x+\overrightarrow y)\cdot (\overrightarrow x + \overrightarrow y)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the correct formula is:
$$
||\vec x + \vec y||=\sqrt{(\vec x+\vec y)\cdot(\vec x+\vec y) }
$$

that, using the distributivity of dot product becomes
$$
||\vec x + \vec y||=\sqrt{(\vec x\cdot \vec x )+(\vec y\cdot \vec y )+2(\vec x\cdot \vec y ) }=\sqrt{||\vec x||^2+||\vec y||^2+2(\vec x\cdot \vec y ) }
$$
and this is a vectorial version of the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) as you can see fro the figure, where : $\overrightarrow{AB}=\vec x$, $\overrightarrow{AC}=\vec x$ and $\overrightarrow{AD}=\vec x+\vec y$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I feel this may be too easy..

$$(\vec x+ \vec y)\cdot (\vec x+ \vec y) = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i+y_i)(x_i+y_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_i + \sum_{i=1}^n y_iy_i +2 \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_j $$ $$= \vec x \cdot \vec x + 2 (\vec x \cdot \vec y) + \vec y \cdot \vec y. $$